# Replace regular expression placeholder followed by number in Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, placeholder

Let's say I want to add a `0` after every word

```
(\w+)
```

The following replacement string doesn't work.

```
$10
```

So, how do I convert

```
this is my string
```

into

```
this0 is0 my0 string0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use braces around the group ID in the replacement string:

```
${1}0
```

The braces tell the regex engine that the number inside them is the actual Group ID. The `0` that will follow will be treated as a literal zero.

[image]

BTW, you can also get the same result with `\w+` regex and `${0}0` replacement string, no need in capturing groups.

Or, using `\n` syntax, it works like this:

```
   Find: (\w+)
Replace: \10
```

[image]

Comment: @Tushar: I suppose that all depends on what regex library is used.

Comment: @Tushar If there are > 9 groups, $10 is the tenth group. Anyway, most RE flavours, simply doesn't replace if the ***x***-th group does not exist.